# Is it possible to stop Hibernate during a save?

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I have an application that uploads large files in a structured format in to a database. The Structure is such that a Data object is saved down holding a collection of DataRow objects.

Sometimes these files can be saving for a considerable amount of time and during this save a user may decide to cancel the operation.

My question is, short of killing the JVM is there a way to stop the process of persisting the Data object? Any thoughts, including change to the persistence technology are welcome.

Here's the method from my DAO that's called to persist the Data objects.

```
@Override
public Data saveData(Data data) {

    Transaction transaction = null;

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Data merged = null;
    try{
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        merged = (Data) session.merge(data);
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();         
        throw e;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return merged;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the actual question but you could do the save asynchronously. Then the user need not know how long it takes to save.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to realize that persisting your huge data in chunks, if it is possible. Persisting- Service should be considered as asynchrone process, so that the clients could work with your it concurrently, while the data is being persisted. You can use a thread local variable like "isCanceled" with initial value "false". In every iteration, you can check, if the variable is set to "true" and cancel persist operation. But, you had to consider a logic, to remove the persisted entries from your database, if you need a rollback logic.

Comment: I don't want my data committed until the entire structure is ready, Hibernate handles batching for me anyway, and other applications view that data so this isn't an option, I need to stop the hibernate persist and let it roll-back itself.

Answer (score -1):

Set the session as parameter, so that you can kill the session and make a rollback.

Comment: call session.close()? 

Will that cause and exception and allow the transaction to roll back?

Comment: Its down voted because it is not the good way .. the way abvoe is the better way

Comment: Committing each bit individually rather than managing everything within transaction is not better.

I don't want individual rows making it in to my database, I want either all or nothing which is the RIGHT way to deal with transactions. 

Is there any particularly bad repercussions of doing it like this that you can think of.